# Person 1 get email for city1,city2,city3 instead of just city1

Tags: python

I have citylist, emaillist. I get the data for them from the database. Then I want to send a customized email based on the city of the person.

If I have

```
for email in emaillist:
    for city in citylist:
         sendemail()
```

Then it sends person 1 the email for city1,city2,city3. Person 2 the email for city1,city2, city3. Person 3 the email for city1, city2, city 3.

But if I change it to

```
for city in citylist:
    for email in emailist:
       sendemail()
```

Then it will send person 1 city1, city2, city3 email and person 2 and person 3 won't get emails. How could I change it so that person 1 gets city 1 email, person 2 gets city 2 email and person 3 gets city 3 email?

EDIT: zip still sends person 1 city 1, city 2 email, person 2, city 1, city 2 email.

EDIT2:

```
for email, c in zip(emaillist, citylist):


    city, state =c.split(",")
```

....

```
    to_email= Email(email)
    content = Content("text/plain", message)
    mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
```

Comment: Are `citylist` and `emailist` *actually* lists, or are they generators?

Comment: Thery're actually lists. I tried the zip function listed below and that worked.

Comment: You might want to change your data structure if you have multiple persons from the same city or same person links to many cities. A dict may be better.

Comment: Why would a dict be better? I am only putting them in those lists so I can send the emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
for email, city in zip(emaillist, citylist):
     sendemail()
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks for answering so fast. I'll check the answer once the time has passed.

Comment: Actually I tried it again and it still sends person 1 the city 1, city 2 email and person 2 city 1, city 2 email.

Comment: In your real code, you're passing `email` and `city` as arguments to the `sendemail` function, right?

Comment: Actually I have for email, c in zip(emaillist, citylist): Then city, state =c.split(",") to_email= Email(email) content = Content("text/plain", message) content = Content("text/plain", message) I will post above so it's easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your help.